# Error when I try to access to one endpoint node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express

I just build one Api Rest to register users but by the moment I can access to this endpoint `http://localhost:5000/api/user/register/`. `Cannot GET /api/user/register/`
This is my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
require('./database.js')
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
//import routes
const authRoute = require('./routes/user');

//json middleware (post, get requests)..
app.use(express.json());
//middlewares
app.use('/api/user', authRoute);

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Running on port 5000'))
```

This is the content of my user.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/register', async (req, res) =>{

    res.send({msg: "welcome"})

});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is the structure of my project:

[image]

I don't know what I doing wrong.
Any idea guys I will appreciate it..
thanks so much.

Comment: try using endpoint => http://localhost:5000/api/user/register
don't use / after register and its a post request make sure you are not using get method where you use it

Comment: Hi @PriyankaGiri the error continues. I don't know why. In my old proyect work of this way.

Comment: try using postman or something to test post api. The error occured cause when you hit the url in browser, it's get request.

Comment: That's correct!! thanks bro.. now I have fixed the problem.. I will do.. Thanks

Comment: @ggorlen ok bro no problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to access directly to a "post" route with the browser

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) =>{

    res.send({msg: "welcome"})

});
```

To access from the browser we need to use a "GET" route:

```
router.get('/register', async (req, res) =>{

    res.send({msg: "welcome"})

});
```

of this way we can access to this endpoint through the browser